# Let $I$ be an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$. Prove that $I=\langle m \rangle$ for some $m \in \Bbb{ Z}$

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $I$ be an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$. Prove that $I=\langle m \rangle$ for
>   some $m \in \Bbb{ Z}$.

Definition: Let $m \in \Bbb{Z}$ we define the principal ideal generated by $m $ as $\langle m \rangle=\{mx:x \in \Bbb{Z}\}$.

Thoughts: I know $\langle m \rangle=m\Bbb{Z}$ so all I need to show is that every ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$ can be written as $m\Bbb{Z}$.

I want to give some more input but I really can't think of where to begin.

I have dealt with a specific case of $2\Bbb{Z} \unlhd \Bbb{Z}$ and shown this to be true so for $I=2\Bbb{Z}$ we have $I=\langle 2 \rangle$.

I understand it for these specific cases but I'm not sure on how to generalise it.

Comment: Hint. Let $m$ be the smallest positive element of $I$ (how do you know there is one?); then show $m$ generates $I$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have managed a decent chunk now. I have managed to prove such an $m$ exists and moreover $m\Bbb{Z} \subset I$. If I can prove $I \subset m \Bbb{Z}$ then I will be done but I am struggling on this?

Comment: Edit: Done now thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $I$ is not the zero ideal so there exists a positive element. By the well-ordering principle there exists a smallest positive element $b\in I$. We claim that $I=\langle b \rangle$.

One inclusion is obvious. For the other proceed by contradiction. Suppose there exists $a\in I$ such that $a\notin\langle b \rangle$. Use euclidean division with remainder to get a contradicition.

Comment: Yeah that was what I did :-)

Comment: @Chris If you'd been just a little faster you could have answered your own question (which is allowed here). You can do it anyway - fill in the details.